# Избавиться от циклов if

Tags: javascript

Проверяю мой класс `games` на название игры. Проверку делаю циклом `if`, но игр будет около 30 и что 30 циклов `if` делать? Не правильно же. Решить мою проблему?

```
  var game_name = document.getElementsByClassName("games")[0].innerHTML;
    if(game_name === 'games1'){
        games1();
    }
    if(game_name === 'games2'){
        games2();
    }
    if(game_name === 'games3'){
        games3();
    }
```

Comment: Может switch? А?

Comment: Да, кстати. If - это не цикл.

Comment: Подозреваю, у вас изначально архитектура какая-то неправильная, раз вам приходится писать подобное

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(game_name) {
  case "game1":
    game1();
    break;
  case "game2":
    game2();
    break;
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Может лучше массив функций?

```js
//Массив функций
var games = [
  function() { console.log("игра 0"); }, 
  function() { console.log("игра 1"); }, 
  function() { console.log("игра 2"); }
];
//Выбор игры
var game = prompt("Введите id игры (0 ... "+games.length+")");

//Проверить игру на существование
try {
  games[game]();
}
// Вывести сообщение при исключении
catch
{
  console.log("Такой игры нет");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тому, что у вас все фунции игр лежат в глобальной области видимости, и названия совпадают с именами функций, проще всего вызвать функцию по имени в глобальном объекте(window).

```
var game_name = ...;
var game = window[game_name];
if (game) game();
else console.error('Unknown game', game_name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Спасибо, почитал документацию. Нашел оптимальное

```
var games = {
    'game1': game1,
    'game2': game2,
    'game3': game13
};


games[game_name]();
```

Comment: Это решение на 90% является копией решения @Duoxx.

Comment: @user263096, на самом деле не является. и разница весьма значительна